# Android MPAndroidChart entry get values

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I'm working with MPAndroidChart on my app for drawing line charts, and I need to know the X and Y values of a touched item. My current code is:

```
chart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.weightChart);

chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
        weights.get(e.getXIndex());
        Log.i("Entry", String.valueOf(e));
        Log.i("dataSetIndex", String.valueOf(dataSetIndex));
        Log.i("Highlight", String.valueOf(h));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected() {

    }
});
```

So that when an iten is touched, dataSetIndex is always `0`,

`Highlight` is: `Highlight, xIndex:` x value`, dataSetIndex: 0, stackIndex (only stacked barentry): -1`,

and `Entry` is: `Entry, xIndex:` x value `val (sum):` y value

So, how could I get the X and Y values from the entry without having to format the Entry?

Thanks a lot

Comment: whether you got solution?

Answer (score 0):

I know its pretty late to answer this, and you probably already found a work-around to it. But for posterity's sake, here's how I do things when it comes to getting the touched point and it's values;

```
chart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
            Log.d(TAG, "y value: " + e.getY());
            Log.d(TAG, "x value: " + e.getX());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });
```

simple and clean.